# Data Valuses for this inventory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out the variables on this table:

[image]

I want to follow this table concept and its variables.
The only thing I know at the moment and figured out is the **Date** should use **timeStamp** Could you use something like stamp on **stock in,out** and **stock on hand** as well?So that I could generate the results of any changes that happend on that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schema:

```
-- drop table if exists inventory;
create table inventory
(   itemId varchar(20) primary key, -- you choose the sizings
    theDate date not null,  -- not this is just a date, not a datetime. It follows your picture info
    description varchar(200) not null,  -- you choose the sizings
    stockIn int not null,
    stockOut int not null,
    onHand int not null,
    updtDT datetime not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Load test data:

```
insert inventory(itemId,theDate,description,stockIn,stockOut,onHand,updtDt) values
('6222-B','2014-09-27','Device 5',0,200,600,'2016-04-10 12:00'),
('9000-M','2014-09-27','Widget 1001',0,400,1800,'2016-04-10 12:00'),
('9000-XX','2014-09-28','Gadget 12',0,200,1650,'2016-04-10 12:00');
```

Touch a row with updated data:

```
update inventory 
set onHand=1900,updtDt=now()
where itemId='9000-XX';
```

Show data updated today:

```
select * from inventory where date(updtDt)=current_date();

+---------+------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| itemId  | theDate    | description | stockIn | stockOut | onHand | updtDT              |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| 9000-XX | 2014-09-28 | Gadget 12   |       0 |      200 |   1900 | 2016-05-29 00:24:51 |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Granted, I may have an extra date in my table. Maybe you only require a single datetime and that is it (not a date and a datetime). But the `date()` function, when used against a datetime column, will produce just the date output. So experiment accordingly.

Comment: But I think I needed A timestamp on this one?because if I use date I could not generate a report of all that happened in the stocks right?example I want to know what changes happened in May 26-29 and the table will show what happen during that span of time.like multiple rows of theDate in your example.

Comment: I did not comprehend what the Date column was on your picture. So I just created a column for that. Whatever in the world it means. The updtDT was for updating when the stuff was updated.

Comment: Let me give you an analogy or comparison. Let's say the info was on States and population. And the `theDate` was the date the state entered the Union (creation date if you will). And the other data was, say, population. `theDate` would never change. But the population would and the `updtDT` would reflect when that updated happened.

Comment: So, you can have a datetime column that contains a date and a time component in it. It is your choice on a given report how you want the data to be given (or just skip the column). If you want a Date coming out of a Datetime, you merely apply the date() function to it.

Comment: It's getting clearer now thanks for the idea.`select * from inventory where date(updtDt)=current_date();` will only generate one row of changes  that happned on a day right?What if I needed like a report that happned within that table for a month?The table should generate rows with different date and changes that happned on the datas.I think this is what I need.

Comment: `where date(updtDt)='2014-02-17'` .... `where updtDt between '2014-03-01' and '2014-03-31 23:59:59'` .... whatever you want. You can use the `month()` and `year()` functions also.

Comment: oh crap.And that will generate the changes for the whole month.It's all about the query after all.I thought I needed to change the dataType.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the data type for the columns you mentioned should be INTEGER